# Where are Xcode 8 templates stored?

Tags: xcode, templates

I've browsed sources that say Xcode looks for templates at:

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates`

but I see no such directory. Is there a new location? I want to make a custom template.

Comment: Are you looking for the supplied templates or the place to store your own custom templates?

Comment: I read this article: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-custom-xcode-templates that says to store custom templates here `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Custom` but there's no `Templates` directory. The article came out earlier this year so I'm wondering if things have since changed.

Comment: You need to create it. That's where I have mine and Xcode 8 sees them just fine.

Comment: Got it. I was confused whether `Templates` was supposed to already exist. Thanks

Comment: @rmaddy that should go as an answer :)

Answer (score 31):

There are multiple Library folders that Xcode.app searches.

Apple stores the *default* Templates that come with the app here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates
```

You can add your own *custom* Templates to one of the standard Library folders, most likely you want "per user", which is here:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
```

But you could also choose "/Library" instead of "~/Library" if you want your templates to be accessible between multiple user accounts.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to have them added to the project and synced across git users?

Comment: @user1898712 Add all templates in git and create alias for it in `Templates` folder