# Xcode 14: Missing Template Folder: Create My Own?

Tags: xcode, templates

When browsing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/` to create my own custom template, it seems I am missing the `Templates` folder.

[image]

From what I've researched ([like here](https://blog.kulman.sk/creating-your-own-xcode-templates/)), I assume a `Template` folder should already be present. I searched SO ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Xcode%2014%20template%20folder)) and ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352366/where-are-xcode-8-templates-stored)) but cannot find any recent Xcode 14 related posts that explains 1) why it hasn't been already created and 2) if I should create my own instead.

What do I do ***when the Template folder is missing***? Do create my own, or has it moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: yes, I created my own Template folder, and it worked. Here's what I did...

Within `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/`, I added `Templates/File Templates/` and then I created a new folder to house my custom templates.

To build my own templates easily, I started with the source files in Xcode:

1. I navigated to Xcode in the `/Applications` folder.
2. Then right-clicked on the app and selected "Show Package Contents"
3. Followed this path: `Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates`
4. Found the folder package I wanted (which was `MultiPlatform/User Interface` and copied the entire folder (`SwiftUI View.xctemplate`).
5. Pasted the folder and it's files to the file path above in the User Library
6. And made my edits to the Swift file!

Simple. See here:

[image]

I hope this can be helpful to someone and save time.

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to add predefined swift package into TemplateInfo.plist?